# Downloading/Caching Google Maps for Offline Use

Tags: android, google-maps, offline

I'd like to be able to implement this in an Android app, and I thought it was possible with the newest Google Maps API release, but I haven't seen much discussion on the topic. Ideally, you'd be able to download/cache maps for a certain region for later offline use. Is it only possible to do this via the Google Maps 5 application and not the API without violating the ToS? I know OpenStreetMap and others allow this, but I believe Google Maps still offers superior mapping and the most widespread usage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about legal issues aren't on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it only possible to do this via the Google Maps 5 application and not the API without violating the ToS?

Correct, though AFAIK it's not even physically possible with the API.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was sort of figuring, since no one was talking about it.

Comment: Has this perhaps changed with today's update?  I know offline downloading is available within the Maps app, but I don't see anything about it in the API documentation yet.

Comment: @harrison_m: If by "today's update" you mean that the Maps app's offline caching capability is moved out of the Labs menu, no, that does not affect `MapView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, is it allowed with Map API V2?

Answer (score 20):

Downloading and caching the Google Maps assets is against the Google Maps API [TOS](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html).

Check the [TOS](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html) section 8:

License Restrictions.  Except as expressly permitted under the Terms, or unless you have received prior written authorization from Google (or, as applicable, from the provider of particular Content), the license granted to you in Section 7 is conditioned on your adherence to all of the restrictions in this Section 8.  Under this Section 8, you must not (nor may you permit anyone else to):

> 8.2.  copy, translate, modify, create a derivative work of, pre-fetch, cache, or publicly display any Content or any part thereof.

Answer (score 11):

There are 3rd party Maps API-s which enable to do this, like [Nutiteq maps SDK](http://www.nutiteq.com/map-api). Not with Google maps, as it is really against their ToS, but with Bing (with Enterprise license), OpenStreetMap (free) or other map sources.

Disclaimer: I'm developer of it.

Comment: Thank you, I'm already using your SDK and it's great! Although I'm having trouble caching map assets (places). I can cache/load the tiles fine, but I can't seem to cache any added features. Is that possible?

Comment: We have just created improved solution for offline POI handling (data in database + spatial index files + clustering). Contact nutiteq.com/forum or support@nutiteq.com if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use GoogleMapsRipper  2.0.4 from http://www.blueblackworks.com
GoogleMapsRipper is mapping software that allows you to download both satellite imagery, topographic and  road maps from Google Maps, Bing Maps and OpenStreet Maps.

Answer (score 0):

According [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) 10.1.3(b) you can do it temporally on mobile device.

This [project](http://code.google.com/p/robertprojects/) implement it, I can't provide particular example but you can dig in into it coz it open-source.