# Offline Google Maps with App Building

Tags: android, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to cache Google map tiles for offline usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109369/how-to-cache-google-map-tiles-for-offline-usage)

Google just barely came out with Maps for Android 5.7 that includes the ability to download a map area for offline use. I'm working on an app in which we use Google Maps via the API. It seemed to me that in a previous version of the app that the MapView would use the downloaded, cached area from within our app. But now, all of the sudden, when I'm offline the App doesn't seem to use or have any cache at all. Should the downloaded cache work offline even for apps that use Google Maps via the API? If I'm online it will work fine, using the debug API key.

Comment: I don't know if the situation has changed but this post seems to imply that the offline usage doesn't apply to the API:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889080/downloading-caching-google-maps-for-offline-use

Comment: I think that response is here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/6183453/1056511

Comment: Hicham, please post this as a short Answer (=write the same in answer box), and I'll accept it as a bounty answer if nothing better arises.