# Android Google Map caching in MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps

I am playing around with the Google API Map Activity.

Recently Google Maps for Android released a new feature for caching of map data. Does anyone know how I can do that in my app as well?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: Trying to elaborate a bit more on this since the last post was almost a year ago. Maybe things have changed, **well I hope.** --> So even though we're able to pre-cache a map using Google's Maps application, we cannot implement it on our own self-developed applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not with the API at least. Also caching map tiles is against Google's terms of service.

See here: [Downloading/Caching Google Maps for Offline Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889080/downloading-caching-google-maps-for-offline-use). Sums it up pretty well.

It would be nice to do so as I have experimented with ways (unofficially) to cache map tiles until one day I read the TOS and then I stopped.

Comment: This is no longer true with the TOS...
http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/download-map-area-added-to-labs-in.html

Not sure why I was down voted either

Comment: That's great for Google Maps users but for developers: Section 8.2 of the [TOS](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html) still states you must not `copy, translate, modify, create a derivative work of, pre-fetch, cache, or publicly display any Content or any part thereof.`

Comment: Thanks Sevado. Since it is still in labs I assume they have not decided to allow that availability to developers. With that said, do you know of a suitable alternative that has similar functionality to Google maps but allows caching of imagery and the ability to load in custom imagery?

Comment: The only other alternative I know is OpenStreetMap. It is the most extensive and extensible and there are a lot of applications already built on top of it. However it does not have satellite or aerial imagery like Google Maps does so you will have to provide your own.