# Android: Tracking GPS location

Tags: android, location

I was wondering a few things:

1. Is there any way to track the GPS location of an android device with NO wifi?
2. If so, how could I trace the path on my android maps app (ie. a red line visually representing where I am going)

Thank you.

Comment: To display the maps you would need internet access to download the viewing region, unless Google's Maps API allows for downloading maps, such as in the Google Maps app

Comment: I used Maps Forge. All I am doing with it is uploading pictures, audio and video to a server at specific locations. I was wondering if I could with NO wifi. Then if so, I wanted to track the locations of where I went with a line to the next upload.

Comment: See [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4889763/1134705)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a phone, you could write an application that uses the base station signals to triangulate your location, but accuracy would vary.

You could also buy an external GPS usb device - eg: Garmin GPS18x, and write an app to poll it via a serial port. It's not hard.

If you need to upload to a server, you will need a connection, so other than wifi, a cellular plan is your next best option. If you don't need real time upload, you could store the photos and gps data to upload at your convenience.

To trace the route, loop through your points and create polylines between consecutive ones, eg: 0-1,1-2,2-3, etc. [See related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps).