# MapFragments with offline maps?

Tags: android, mapfragment

I'm working on an app that shows the maps of only a single city. i'm working with offline maps for this app. For this reason is it possible to use MapFragments with offline maps?? Can anybody guide me in this regard??

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible to use MapFragment and the Maps v2 API offline. 
This is useful if you want to show your own map material.

(However as hinted by Audrius K, you are not allowed to cache any GoogleMaps data, but I don't think that was you question anyway.)

(There was a bug a few weeks ago about initialized the map component offline but that bug has been reported to Google and fixed. I mention it in case you'd find mention of that bug in your research)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Googles Term of services even lets you to use it offline. Possible answer [Downloading/Caching Google Maps for Offline Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889080/downloading-caching-google-maps-for-offline-use)

You always can try to use OpenStreetMaps, but that won't work with map fragment :)

Comment: I don't think the question concerned the data but the API.