# How to store cache in google map programatically

Tags: android, dictionary

How to store cache in Google map programmatically. After cache it will be working with offline.

please suggest source or any link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889080/downloading-caching-google-maps-for-offline-use

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the Google maps snapshot method to save the current visible map's snapshot and save this in the sdcard. futher more you can view all the stored images later.

```
private void button_listener() {
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                Bitmap bitmap;

                @Override
                public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    bitmap = snapshot;
                    try {
                           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Download/TeleSensors.png");
                           bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            map.snapshot(callback);

        }
    });
}
```

make sure you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest file