# Google Map Offline

Tags: android, google-maps, offline

I want to create an android app which will show the city bus routes(i.e bus stops,stations,etc) on Google Map. Will it be possible to download the Google Map for a particular area(city in this case) and provide it with app by default, So that people can use it in offline mode?

Or may be as an alternative, can a option can be provided later to user after installing app, to download map for offline use?

Comment: have you tried to replace google maps with [osmdroid-open streetmap for andriod](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) which support offline-map-caching?

Comment: well i was not having any idea about that. Thats why I made this post, to know the alternatives. Have you used it ??? would you please share your opinion/review

Comment: the lib-sources contain a demo-app for the lib that does everythink i need. i havent implemented an app of my own yet.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4889796/2359161

This is not possible while using your own app with Google maps, as it is against their terms of service.

Comment: But the problem is that the downloaded map can be accessed by Google Map ONLY. How will my app will be able to access that data ??

Comment: There is a reference to Nutiteq maps SDK as an alternative. Do you have any experience/opinion about that?

Comment: @user2054624 Sorry, I personally have only used Google maps for Android apps, haven't tried other maps.