# How to show google map offline?

Tags: android, google-maps

How i can show google map offline?

I have gone through various stackoverflow question and answer but not able to find solution.

I have implemented `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` and i am showing direction from one point to other. I have got coordinates from GMapV2Direction. Now i want to show this as offline.

Following are the links i got from stackoverflow but not useful.

- [Google Map Offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021489/google-map-offline)
- [TileProvider using local tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles)

Plese help!!!

Answer (score 4):

[See this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles) or [this one](http://guides.cocoahero.com/google-maps-android-custom-tile-providers.html). Basically you just create your own tileprovider and access tiles locally. Totally doable with the v2 api.
[API Reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider)

There's some false information floating around out there that the v2 google maps api requires an internet connection. There was a but where the api would require a single access after app install to verify with Google Play services, but I believe this has been fixed. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056156/using-the-android-google-maps-api-v2-as-a-viewer-of-offline-tiles-is-it-possibl) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4817)

Comment: How to download Tiles?

Comment: follow this link            https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Comment: here you will get code  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles

Comment: No above code is not helpful for me. I need code for downloading tiles to keep offline.

Comment: i sharing an example please study this hope it wil helpfull to you  https://github.com/mapsme/api-android