# Google Map offline not working if installed without internet connection

Tags: android, google-maps

I've downloaded map tiles from http://tile.openstreetmap.org. What I want to do is use this map tiles with google map Library. I've followed the this links
- [How to show google map offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203151/how-to-show-google-map-offline)
- [Google Map Offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021489/google-map-offline)
- [TileProvider using local tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784841/tileprovider-using-local-tiles)

And have working map activity.
Here is CustomTileProvider class

```
public class CustomTileProvider implements TileProvider{
    public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
        Log.e("TAG","Get tile image");
        byte[] image = readTileImage(x, y, zoom);
    }

}
```

The problem I'm currently facing is when I uninstall the app and install, and run whithout internet connect the getTile method never been called. Can any body know why this is happening?

Edit:
I've stored the downloaded tiles inside assets folder with the following file structure

```
   /map
      /zoom/
          /x
             /y
```

Comment: So they are there at reinstall. And i understand that you never see this log: `Log.e("TAG","Get tile image");`?

Comment: Yes  @greenapps. that is problem i'm facing

Comment: Then what can we do for you,? You should show the code which IS called i think. Where does it stop?