# Save gData from Google Maps on our data server

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps JavaScript API in my online web application for commercial use.

Can I save the GeoData I get from this API on our data server to not make the same API call over and over again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is against the Google Maps API TOS, see this previous question: [Downloading/Caching Google Maps for Offline Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889080/downloading-caching-google-maps-for-offline-use)